# input JSON data type in MySql column

Tags: php, mysql, algolia

I'm using Algolia as my site's search engine, Algolia wants '_geoloc' attribute to be a JSON object like this in order to enable searching based on locations :-

```
{
    "rahn": "e369853df766fa44e1ed0ff613f563bd",
    "_geoloc": { "lat" : 23.788117809722195 , "lng" : 86.41868225381391 }
},
```

But when I exported my Mysql database in JSON its '_geoloc' attribute is like this :-

```
{
    "sadad": "32rf4rsdf43444rtte4e3rrt3342334",
    "_geoloc": "{ \"lat\" : 23.788117809722195 , \"lng\" : 86.41868225381391 }"
},
```

Row Info

name :- _geoloc

type :- longtext

collation :- utf8mb4_bin

attributes :- none

Comment: You have assigned the value into the table incorrectly. You have provided not an object value `{ "lat" : 23.788117809722195 , "lng" : 86.41868225381391 }` but string value `"{ \"lat\" : 23.788117809722195 , \"lng\" : 86.41868225381391 }"`.

Comment: I'm not providing it its automatically changed

Comment: No - 99%. Show INSERT INTO statement which was be used for to insert this value into the table.

Comment: $a_bag = "UPDATE client_storage SET _geoloc = '{ \"lat\" : $client_lat , \"lng\" : $client_long }' WHERE client_id = 567"; my PHP query

Comment: This is not a query, this is PHP code. Show the value of `$a_bag` after PHP variables to values substitution at least.

Comment: I'm not understanding what value u want to know

Comment: i also want to know that if I'm changing data type of column to json in MySQL why its changing to longtext

Comment: *if I'm changing data type of column to json in MySQL* How do you do this? show SQL query. And what is precise MySQL version?

Comment: Through PhpMyAdmin go to structures of a table and u can change there, my MySQL version is 7.4.12

Comment: *my MySQL version is 7.4.12* Not exists. This may be PHP version or something else... execute `SELECT VERSION();` and provide complete output.

Comment: 10.4.16-MariaDB

Comment: MariaDB does not implement JSON. It uses JSON keyword as an alias for LONGTEXT datatype.

Comment: so what will you suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Since I didn't find any solution to my problem I have done this other alternative i.e. I used Python for doing these changes to my JSON and You can do it too to do any changes to any type of file.
Here's my python code to do this:-

```
import json
with open('Your_file_location.json', encoding='cp850') as json_file:
    prd_json_file = json.load(json_file)
    for prd in prd_json_file:
        if(prd['_geoloc'] != ''):
            prd['_geoloc'] = json.loads(prd['_geoloc'])
        else:
            prd['_geoloc'] = { "lat": 23.378536756304715, "lng": 85.33722513906919 }
with open('Your_file_location.json','w', encoding='cp850') as json_file:
    json.dump(prd_json_file,json_file)
print('success')
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the next code:

```sql
$a_bag = "UPDATE client_storage 
          SET _geoloc = JSON_OBJECT('lat', $client_lat, 'lng', $client_long) 
          WHERE client_id = 567";
```

and check the value saved into the column.

Comment: i tried it but its same

Comment: Please check the value via command-line client `mysql.exe`.

Comment: { "lat" : 54.788117809722195 , "lng" : 57.41868225381391 } this is how it looks in mysql row but when i export it in json form its again the same

Comment: @Annone *this is how it looks in mysql row* This is correct JSON value. *when i export it in json form its again the same* If so then this is not MySQL issue. Read your client software (Algolia) documentation.

Comment: sorry sir but is not a problem from algolia and your solution is not working

Comment: @Annone MariaDB stores correct value. Built-in client can retrieve it correctly. Your client cannot. And you think that this is not your client but MariaDB issue nevetheless? Where it the logic?